# Jquery: appending li if variable equals other variable

Tags: javascript, jquery

Trying to set up adding slides to flexslider 2 in shopify.

EDITED THE CODE, to suggestions, but still no go.

Basically, the idea is if variable equals another variable that is picked up from shopify settings, then script appends li with a slide. If not- nothing happens.

I'm as noob as they come in JQ. Can some one point out my mistake, please?
Thanks!

```
$(document).ready(function(){
var show = "block" ;
var showsetting1 = "{{ settings.mainslide_display1 }}" ;

if (showsetting1 === show)
{
$(".flexslider ul").append ('<li class="slider-image1 slideswidth"><img src="{{ 'slider-image-1.jpg' | asset_url }}">');
}
else {}
});
```

Comment: The most obviouse solution here is to learn the javascript/jquery syntax

Comment: It would be helpful to see (a) some of the slider HTML, so we can tell if your selector is correct and (b) the *rendered* output on shopify, where `{{ settings... }}`, etc. have been replaced by their "real" text.

Answer (score 2):

There are a lot of problems with your code. First of all you should be using the `==` or `===` operators, not the assignment operator `=`. Second of all there are syntax errors.

`$(".flexslider ul").append(...)`.

There are too many problems to list.

Also, variables should be introduced with `var`, not the $ sign, e.g.

`var show = 'block';`