# Jquery, append li on condition

Tags: javascript, jquery, shopify, flexslider

Trying to set up adding slides to flexslider 2 in shopify.

Opened a thread, where a few syntax mistakes were pointed out. Fixed them but didn't get any replies since then, and I really need to get it going. So, here is 2nd try.

Basically, the idea is if variable equals another variable that is picked up from shopify settings, then script appends li with a slide. If not- nothing happens.

I'm as noob as they come in JQ. Can some one point out my mistake, please?

Thanks!

```
$(document).ready(function(){
var show = "block" ;
var showsetting1 = "{{ settings.mainslide_display1 }}" ;

if (showsetting1 === show)
{
$(".flexslider ul").append('<li class="slider-image1 slideswidth"><img src="{{ 'slider-image-1.jpg' | asset_url }}">');
}
else {}
});
```

Comment: Why the empty `else`?

Comment: well apparently your condition is never true, as you set them just before.

Comment: Also, how would showsetting1 be equal to show? They're two constant strings and you're explicitly setting them to different things.

Comment: The if statement doesn't make sense. You're setting the show and showsetting1 variables to 2 different values, so they're never going to match.

Comment: He's assuming (maybe correctly) that Shopify will run it through the Liquid engine and expand the `{{...}}` chunks into their defined values.

Comment: possible duplicate of [Jquery: appending li if variable equals other variable](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/23662051/jquery-appending-li-if-variable-equals-other-variable)

Comment: @Paul Roub, exactly on liquid assumption.

Comment: Like Paul Roub said, the showsettings1 is probably being set to a templated value. The issue I see in the append statement is a space between "append" and the first bracket.

Comment: @bitwiser. removed the space, but still no show

Comment: It's because Javascript doesn't parse liquid snytax, you're setting the variable as the raw liquid code.

Comment: Are you getting any js errors, or just nothing happening? Are you sure your html is correct? (ie. you have a container element with the class name "flexslider" and a ul element inside that)

This seems like something easily debugged using something like chrome's dev tools.

Answer (score 2):

According to [this thread on the Shopify forums](http://ecommerce.shopify.com/c/ecommerce-design/t/using-liquid-in-javascript-trying-to-get-collection-title-in-jquery-callback-53043), you can only use liquid syntax in Javascript if you make their file extensions .js.liquid (and .css.liquid, likewise, for CSS). If you change the extension of your javascript file, it should properly parse the liquid syntax rather than evaluating it as a string as written.

Answer (score 1):

You are missing the closing tag on your img element and li element
You can also safely remove the else condition

```
$(document).ready(function(){
    var show = "block",
        showsetting1 = "{{ settings.mainslide_display1 }}" ;

    if (showsetting1 === show)
    {
        $(".flexslider ul").append ('<li class="slider-image1 slideswidth"><img src="{{ 'slider-image-1.jpg' | asset_url }}" /></li>'); // You are missing closing tag on img and li
    } // the else condition is not necessary as it does nothing
});
```